# Ldap and afresco 5.2 synchronization

Tags: ldap, alfresco

I am currently configuring alfresco to use ldap server for authentication. I followed the offecial documentation and i updated alfresco-global.properties file, i can log in with ldap users but i don't see any group of dap and i see only ldap users who already connect with alfresco if a user did not logged in  alfresco i don't see him . i am using alfresco 5.2  and apache LDAP and this is my alfresco-global.properties file and the ldap hiarchy.

[image]

```
# User name format ..
ldap.authentication.active=true

ldap.authentication.userNameFormat=cn\=%s,ou\=users,o\=mojo
alfresco.authentication.authenticateCIFS=false
ntlm.authentication.sso.enabled=false
ntlm.authentication.mapUnknownUserToGuest=false
ldap.authentication.allowGuestLogin=false

# IP address or name of your LDAP server - (port 389 is the default for LDAP)
ldap.authentication.java.naming.provider.url=ldap://localhost:10389

# Enable synchronisation ..
ldap.synchronization.active=true

ldap.authentication.escapeCommasInUid=false
ldap.synchronization.queryBatchSize=0
ldap.synchronization.attributeBatchSize=100
ldap.authentication.escapeCommasInBind=false

# The LDAP context factory to use
ldap.authentication.java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory
# Security ..
ldap.authentication.java.naming.security.authentication=simple
ldap.synchronization.java.naming.security.authentication=simple
ldap.synchronization.java.naming.security.principal=admin
ldap.synchronization.java.naming.security.credentials=secret

# Object class names, OUs ..
ldap.synchronization.groupQuery=(objectclass\=groupOfUniqueNames)
ldap.synchronization.personQuery=(objectclass\=inetOrgPerson)
ldap.synchronization.groupSearchBase=ou\=groups,o\=mojo
ldap.synchronization.userSearchBase=ou\=users,o\=mojo

# The attribute name on people objects to use as the uid in Alfresco
ldap.synchronization.userIdAttributeName=uid
# The attribute on person objects in LDAP to map to the first name property in Alfresco
#ldap.synchronization.userFirstNameAttributeName=givenName
# The attribute on person objects in LDAP to map to the last name property in Alfresco
ldap.synchronization.userLastNameAttributeName=sn
# The attribute on person objects in LDAP to map to the email property in Alfresco
ldap.synchronization.userEmailAttributeName=mail
# The attribute on group objects to map to the authority name property in Alfresco
ldap.synchronization.groupIdAttributeName=cn
# The attribute on group objects to map to the authority display name property in Alfresco
ldap.synchronization.groupDisplayNameAttributeName=cn
# The group type
ldap.synchronization.groupType=groupOfUniqueNames
# The person type
ldap.synchronization.personType=inetOrgPerson
# The attribute on group objects that defines the DN for its members
ldap.synchronization.groupMemberAttributeName=uniqueMember

# If true progress estimation is enabled. When enabled, the user query has to be run twice in order to count entries.
ldap.synchronization.enableProgressEstimation=true
# Requests timeout, in miliseconds, use 0 for none (default)
ldap.authentication.java.naming.read.timeout=0

synchronization.synchronizeChangesOnly=false
```

**This is my alfresco-global.properties**

```
###############################
## Common Alfresco Properties #
###############################
dir.root=C:/ALFRES~1/alf_data
alfresco.context=alfresco
alfresco.host=127.0.0.1
alfresco.port=8080
alfresco.protocol=http
share.context=share
share.host=127.0.0.1
share.port=8080
share.protocol=http
### database connection properties ###
db.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.username=alfresco
db.password=admin
db.name=alfresco
db.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/${db.name}
# Note: your database must also be able to accept at least this many connections. Please see your database documentation for instructions on how to configure this.
db.pool.max=275
db.pool.validate.query=SELECT 1
# The server mode. Set value here
# UNKNOWN | TEST | BACKUP | PRODUCTION
system.serverMode=UNKNOWN
### FTP Server Configuration ###
ftp.port=21
### RMI registry port for JMX ###
alfresco.rmi.services.port=50500
### External executable locations ###
ooo.exe=C:/ALFRES~1/LIBREO~1/App/libreoffice/program/soffice.exe
ooo.enabled=true
ooo.port=8100
img.root=C:\\alfresco-community\\imagemagick
img.coders=${img.root}\\modules\\coders
img.config=${img.root}
img.gslib=${img.root}\\lib
img.exe=${img.root}\\convert.exe
jodconverter.enabled=false
jodconverter.officeHome=C:/ALFRES~1/LIBREO~1/App/libreoffice
jodconverter.portNumbers=8100
### Initial admin password ###
alfresco_user_store.adminpassword=209c6174da490caeb422f3fa5a7ae634
### E-mail site invitation setting ###
notification.email.siteinvite=false
### License location ###
dir.license.external=C:/ALFRES~1
### Solr indexing ###
index.subsystem.name=solr4
dir.keystore=${dir.root}/keystore
solr.host=localhost
solr.port.ssl=8443
### Allow extended ResultSet processing
security.anyDenyDenies=false
### Smart Folders Config Properties ###
smart.folders.enabled=false
### Remote JMX (Default: disabled) ###
alfresco.jmx.connector.enabled=false

### Use Alfresco authentication for admin accounts and LDAP for users ###
authentication.chain=alfrescoNtlm1:alfrescoNtlm,ldap1:ldap
synchronization.allowDeletions=true
## When TESTING, set synchronizeChangesOnly to false
## - this will give FULL synchronization for scheduled synchs
synchronization.synchronizeChangesOnly=false
## Set up regular synchronization with the LDAP server ##
synchronization.syncWhenMissingPeopleLogIn=true
synchronization.syncOnStartup=true
# When TESTING, synchronise every 5 minutes
# secs min hour dom mon dow
synchronization.import.cron=0 0/1 * * * ? 
ldap.synchronization.enableProgressEstimation=true
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that's the right `objectClass` in the group query? Can you use something like Apache Directory Studio of `ldapsearch` to check what your objects really are?

Comment: hey check the post a gain i added a screenshot of apache Directory studio

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. It was resolved when I used a service account with more priviledges. Try testing your LDAP integration with an admin account. Below is my LDAP integration section of alfresco-global.properties for Alfresco Community 201704.

```
### LDAP connection ###
authentication.chain=alfinst:alfrescoNtlm,ldap1:ldap-ad

ntlm.authentication.sso.enabled=false

ldap.authentication.allowGuestLogin=false
ldap.authentication.userNameFormat=%s@example.org
ldap.authentication.java.naming.provider.url=ldap://{domain}
ldap.authentication.defaultAdministratorUserNames=Administrator,alfresco
ldap.synchronization.java.naming.security.principal={valid service account}
ldap.synchronization.java.naming.security.credentials={password for above account}
ldap.synchronization.active=true

# Group
ldap.synchronization.groupSearchBase=cn=Users,dc=exmaple,dc=org

# User
ldap.synchronization.userSearchBase=cn=Users,dc=example,dc=org
ldap.synchronization.userIdAttributeName=sAMAccountName
ldap.synchronization.userFirstNameAttributeName=givenName
ldap.synchronization.userLastNameAttributeName=sn
ldap.synchronization.userEmailAttributeName=mail

# Sync
synchronization.synchronizeChangesOnly=false
synchronization.allowDeletions=true
synchronization.syncWhenMissingPeopleLogIn=true
synchronization.syncOnStartup=true
synchronization.import.cron=0 */15 * * * ?
create.missing.people=false
```

Comment: I would expect to see some logging in `alfresco.log` when something gets wrong about LDAP user permission in ActiveDirectory. Why is it so silent ? Before switching to "a more privilege" account, I would like to be sure it may help based on logging details.